# Using get_tmplate_part() function in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am making a wordpress theme, in which I have different skins and templates, Is it a good idea to use get_template_part() function to load different chunks/templates instead of having one single file. I find it useful however my only concern is, will this function put load on server or effect the performance in any way ? I am using it like below:

```
  /* Post Tags Template */
  get_template_part( 'templates/post_tags' );

  /* Post Meta Template */
  get_template_part( 'templates/post_meta' );
```

Comment: Using `get_template_part` probably won't hurt performance. See a relation question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110927/too-many-get-template-parts) or a newer article [here](http://kovshenin.com/2013/get_template_part/).